# Exercise in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic

Section 4.1, ex. $3.(2)$ of Introduction to mathematical Logic by Richard Hodel.
Express the following statements:

> (2) For every natural number $a$ greater than 1, there is a prime $p$ that divides $a$.

Is the following, in language of FOL, correct:

$\forall a\in \Bbb N \left[a>1\Rightarrow\left(\exists p\in \Bbb N(\forall b\in \Bbb N \lnot(b \vert p)\; \land\; p \vert a\right) \right].$

*Edit*

Reply to @Bram28:

Writing instead of $(\forall b\in \Bbb N \lnot(b \vert p))$ this:

$(\forall b\in \Bbb N(b>1\; \land b\neq p))$
would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You always have that $p|p$, as well as $1|p$, whether $p$ is prime or not.

Hence, the $\forall b\in \Bbb N \lnot(b \vert p)$ part will always be false.

It'll take a bit more work to express that $p$ is a prime ... but take into consideration what I just said, and try again!

Also, the rest of the expression has the right format, good job!

Comment: thanks, edited now.

Comment: @flowian Closer!  First, I assume you mean to use $(\forall b\in \Bbb N(b>1\; \land b\neq p) \to \neg b|p)$ ... but that would also be the case for $p=1$. That is, if this is your way to define a prime, then $1$ becomes a prime ...

Comment: Ah yes, meant to write:  

$\left(\forall b\in \Bbb N\left(b>1\; \land b\neq p\;\land \lnot (b\vert p)\right)\right)$

Comment: @flowian Well, you definitely don;t want to use that, since now you're claiming (among other things), that every number $b$ is greater than $1$, which is clearly false. No, you want to say *if* number $b$ is greater than $1$ and not equal to $p$, *then* it does not divide $p$. So like I did: use a conditional.  But even that's still not right, since you still need to rule out $p$ as a prime.

Comment: Should be correct I think:

$\forall a\in \Bbb N \left[a >1 \to \left(\exists p\left( \forall b\in \Bbb N\left((b>1 \land b\neq p )\to \lnot (b\vert p)\right)\right) \land (p \vert a) \right) \right]$

Comment: @flowian No, like I said: you need to think about the case that $p=1$. Then for any $b>1$ we have $\neg (b|p)$, and we also have $(p|a)$. So, it is *trivial* that this $p$ exists for any $a > 1$ .. which is not what you want. Again, you are effectively defining $1$ to be a prime ... but you need to explicitly rule out $1$ to be a prime. Indeed, $1$ is a special case as far as primes go: we *used* to say: a prime is any number that is only divisible by $1$ and itself.  But, that makes $1$ a prime ... and $1$ *used* to be considered a prime.  But, no more. So, you have to add that $p \neq 1$

Comment: That's news for me that 1 is not considered a prime. How recent this re-definition is?

Comment: Nevermind above comment. The confusion is in the definition "The prime is a number that is divisible by itself and 1". Whereas more precise definition is "A prime is number that has two distinct factors".

Comment: @flowian Exactly. The first is the old definition of primes, the second is the new definition (a prime is a number with exactly two divisors). The first one is easier to formalize, but mathematicians adopted the second definition since with that you can get theorems like the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (every number has a unique prime factorization). But yes, unfortunately when you formalize the second one in first-order logic, it's a little more complicated.